# how to avoid the page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I'm using devexpress components in my ASP application. In page _load() i have bind the ASPXtreelist & initialize at page_init. But when focus particular node page refreshes automatically. Same happens with ASPxMenu item click event. Both events bind the gridview datasource. These controls are placed in ASPxSplitter. I will try to solve using updatepanel but whole updatepanel gets refreshed. How to avoid the page refresh after event?

I also tried this [solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28099/Refresh-Page-Issue-in-ASP-Net).

I have attached my asp markup with this [link](http://www.4shared.com/office/UuqDYsPA/ASP.html) please check.

Thanks

Comment: We need to see some more code. Can you post up your ASPX markup?

Comment: can you not just post the code here instead of uploading it to a file host?

Answer (score 1):

In [ASPxMenu](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxMenuASPxMenutopic) you set [AutoPostback](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxMenuASPxMenuBase_AutoPostBacktopic) to true which in this case causes server side handling of [ItemClick](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxMenuASPxMenuBase_ItemClicktopic) event.
In [ASPxTreeList](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxTreeListASPxTreeListtopic) you set [SettingsBehavior.ProcessFocusedNodeChangedOnServer](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTreeListTreeListSettingsBehavior_ProcessFocusedNodeChangedOnServertopic) to true which causes server side handling of [FocusedNodeChanged](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTreeListASPxTreeList_FocusedNodeChangedtopic) event.

So, your page is refreshed because postback occurs whenever you click on menu item or treelist row.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ASPxTreeList uses its built-in AJAX callbacks and refreshes the own rendering only.

Check this behavior at the [Node Selection - Focused Node](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxTreeListDemos/Selection/FocusedNode.aspx)  demo.

Comment: have you encountered the same results?